# Rendering issue occur running an android app in Android Studio

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

Getting following problem while running an android app to the external device using Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04

```
    Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>

(CoordinatorLayout.java:172) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard  Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2147418374 (3 similar errors not shown)
```

Comment: hello,welcome to stackoverflow.provide releavent code and full stacktrace if you want people to answer it

Comment: check your app gradle file if the following dependency is there:
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' . Just to make sure the support design lib is added to your project , since FAB , Coordinaterlayout etc are part of android support design library

Comment: Note the exception says: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library." Are you?